How exactly does a seashell make the humming sound?
My little brother asked me where the ocean-like sounds came from inside of a sea shell. I told him that the air trapped inside the shell vibrates, making a sound. But then he asked me why the air had to vibrate, and I was stumped. I didn't know the answer to why the air vibrated, or where it derived that energy from. Here are some possible drivers of the sound that I could think of:

The thermal vibrations of the shell.
Random pressure fluctuations in the atmosphere.
The wind that enters the shell through the hole, vibrates and forms the sound like in a flute.

Which one of these (or their combinations/or none at all)  is a plausible driver of the sound?

Have you read Wikipedia?

humming? to me that implies a much lower frequency than I hear from a shell, which seems mostly like a high pitched reflection of ambient noise.

While inside your house, place a shell or a cup or a drinking glass or even a cupped hand over your ear and you will observe the same phenomena. Assuming there is no significant wind inside your house this rules out option 3 as a primary explanation.  What is happening is that the conical shell amplifies residual background noise that we do not normally notice, similar to the way the horn amplifier of an old fashioned gramaphone amplifies the vibrations of the needle on the record player, as in the HMV logo below.

The shell or cuo may block out certain frequencies in the background noise that we are used to, which may also make the other amplified residual frequencies in the background noise more obvious, by contrast.

The nice thing about a cupped hand is you can change the shape and so the dominant frequency, though it's quieter than a hard container.  Apparently you won't hear anything in an anechoic  chamber but I've tried it in places so quiet I could hear my own pulse and there was something.

But the source of noise is not background, it is the ear itself. Yes, ears generate sound and then it is amplified as you explain.

@yarchik there's a lot of debate over that

@ChrisH spontaneous otoacoustic emissions is a well established phenomenon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otoacoustic_emission).

@yarchik WP says SOAEs are fixed frequency, and a cupped hand over the ear gives a broad range with a movable peak as you change the size of the cavity

@ChrisH Can you somehow substantiate your statement about the broad range? Some spectral measurements with "cupped hand over the ear" would be nice to see. On my side, I would like to refer to Fig. 2 in https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/spontaneous-otoacoustic-emission . As can be seen, the spectrum is not monochromatic, and by coupling the source with a resonating cavity, it is not a surprise that some frequencies are enhanced.

@yarchik I don't have a microphone sensitive or small enough (I have one on order for something else so maybe I can do the experiment in a few days). But it's obviously not a single frequency or a simple harmonic series by ear. If you can arrange a telescoping cylinder you can hear the peak of the distribution shift continuously

Your third option is the closest to the case.
The seashell forms a cavity resonator, which will have some characteristic frequency response determined by things like the shape of the shell etc. Ambient sounds are responsible for inducing the vibrations in the first place. You can demonstrate this point to yourself by observing that the sound will either disappear or become much fainter if you take the shell into a very quiet room.

The shell with a small opening forms a Helmholtz resonator that is excited by noise from outside. Image from Formulas of Acoustics, F.P. Mechel pp72. The Wikipedia article has relevant equations for a more uniform cavity- the Q will likely be lower with a natural shape, and there may be additional resonances.

A similar principle is used to amplify the sound from piezoelectric beepers, however the excitation comes from the rear wall of the cavity where an oil-canning element applies a force with applied voltage.
Note: There has been a comment about the use of electrical analogs for analysis of acoustic systems, so apparently it's not a familiar technique to everyone,  I'll reproduce the full list of analogs from the same volume referenced above:

From this paper we have a typical example of modelling of thermal systems using electrical analogs as below:


The question is about a seashell and ear, while this answer displays a RLC electronic circuit. This looks like AI generated nonsense.

@user402514 on the contrary that's a mechanical diagram that just happens to look electrical.

@user402514 It's an electrical analog of a mechanical system. See edit above illustrating the technique for mechanical and thermal systems.

Neither of the three explanations are true. Actually, the seashell amplifies and reflects the sound of your blood flowing through the blood vessels in your ear! That is what you hear as humming.

The question to the answer is: The seashell does not make noise.
The answer to the question: What is the source of what you hear if you close your one ear with a cup and close the other ear competely with wax, is a personal experiment.
If the cup closes acoustically tight, you hear nothing if you are older than 45. The lowest resonance frequency for a cup of 5cm greatest diameter is $$\nu_{\min} = 20*330 /s = 6.5 \text{kHz}$$
If you hear a resonance of the white noise depends on your ears sensitivity.
A long time ago I learned at the III. Institute of Physics in Göttingen, where they specialized on Acoustics of Concerto Halls e.g., by Erwin Meyer about the sensitivity of a young ear with frequency limit  above 30 kHz is such, that the thermal noise of air at the hearable, the pressure treshold of $2*10^{-5} \text{Pa}$ corrsponds to an amplitude of $10^{-11} \text{m}$, is less than the free mean path of the corresponing Brownian motion of a free gas molecule.
Like seeing in the dark, hearing in abolute silence is adapted by evolution to the detection of perturbations of the background noise spectrum by a nearing enemy, that my be thougth of an acoustically absorbing body.
From Wiley online library in German

At lower frequencies, the hearing threshold prevents us from hearing thermal molecular movement and thus a constant noise, and the reduction in sensitivity to low frequencies prevents us from having to hear the sounds of our body, i.e. blood circulation, pulse, digestion, etc.

A hard wall resonance volume over the ear, open or closed, shifts down the effective hearing thresholds wrt. to the inner and outer noise levels.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
